# JQuery autocomplete result style

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to change the style from my AutoComplete result.

I tried:

```
// Only change the inputs
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('fontSize', '10px');
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('width','300px');
```

I searches and could not find out what the class used by the result is, so that I can change its font size and maybe its width.

Thanks.

Using:
[jQuery-UI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

**EDIT:** I need change the css from my result, that comes from my JSON, not from the input. The code you posted, only changes the input, not the result. This is why I asked for the class used by the result list (at least, I believe that is a list). I tried to use fb from ff and could not find it. Thanks again for your patience.

**EDIT2:** I'll use the autocomplete from jQuery UI as example.

[Check this to see the jQuery-UI auto-complete page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

After I type "Ja" in the textbox from the front-page sample, Java and JavaScript will appear as Results, in the little box below the textbox.

*This* little box is what I want to change the CSS of. My code in the sample above only changes my textbox CSS (which I don't need at all).

I don't know if I'm being clear now. I hope so, but if not, please let me know; I'll try harder if needed to show my problem.

**The class for the UL that will contain the result items is what I need.**

**SOLUTION**
As Zikes said in his comment on the accepted answer, here is the solution. You just need to put `ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu{width:300px}` in your CSS file.

This will make all the the results box css have `width:300px` (like the sample).

> I forgot that the results object does not exist on page load, and therefor would not be found and targetted by a call to `$('...').css()`. You'll actually need to put `ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu{width:300px}` in your CSS file, so that it will take effect when the results are generated and inserted into the page.
>   – Zikes

Comment: Please give more info or example source.

Comment: Hi there @user667776, i put two news information as **EDITS**, i hope that i'm ok now. thanks for the tip to increase my information about my question.

Comment: PS: Just to make it clear. the answer is on the **COMMENTS** from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Information on styling the Autocomplete widget can be found here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#theming

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zikes/WxmST/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="auto">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#auto').autocomplete({'source':
    ['abc','abd','abe','abf','jkl','mno','pqr','stu','vwx','yz']
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu{width:400px}

/* 
    targets the first result's <a> element, 
    remove the a at the end to target the li itself 
*/
ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu li:first-child a{
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: hi Zikes, i check there first. i don't like come here to ask before try google or documentation first. I didn't find nothing saying what class is the class of the result. i tried ".ui-autocomplete-input" like i show in the sample, and didn't work. i'm kind lost here atm. Appreciate for the enforce to help me =) IF i miss something there, please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nymos The `ul` markup following the `ui-autocomplete-input` is the results it generates.  By targeting `ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu` you should get what you need.

Comment: @Zikes, thanks for the fast replay ^.^ but it does not work. i use `$('.ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu').css('width', '300px');` and nothing happen, i check in ff error console, and no errors there.

Comment: @Nymos Remove the first `.` from the selector, since it is targetting the `ul` element with the `ui-autocomplete` and `ui-menu` class.  The line should look like `$('ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu').css('width', '300px');`

Comment: @Zikes Thanks again for help me so fast =) i tried it again, as you said. My really sorry for my noob mistake in forget the dot in the ul. =P. But even with the change it didn't work. `$('ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu').css('width', '300px');` is how i tried it. And the magic does not work Q.Q

Comment: @Nymos I forgot that the results object does not exist on page load, and therefor would not be found and targetted by a call to `$('...').css()`.  You'll actually need to put `ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu{width:300px}` in your CSS file, so that it will take effect when the results are generated and inserted into the page.

Comment: @Nymos as an example, I've created this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zikes/TSC3S/

Comment: @Zikes Amazing that works, i was searching in css and was going crazy, until i back here and see your comment =) But i still have one problem. i need it in one item only, not every item. i was using this code. `if (Id[0] == 0) {$('ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu').css('width', '300px');}` Any tips in how should i achieve this ? PS:Marking you as accepted answer, cuz you answer my question. but if you can help me here, i'll be really happy =)

Comment: @Nymos to be clear, do you mean to target the first item every time, or a specific item no matter where it appears in the results?

Comment: @Nymos If you're just after the first item, I've created a jsfiddle to demonstrate that: http://jsfiddle.net/Zikes/WxmST/1/

Comment: Thanks again for the help Zikes =) Works flawless.

Answer (score 16):

I was able to adjust by adding this css to the `<head>` of the document (above the autocomplete javascript).

Some of the following may be more relevant than others. You could make it specific to the autocomplete input if changing these affects other elements you don't want affected.

```
<style type="text/css">
 /* http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#theming*/
.ui-autocomplete { position: absolute; cursor: default; background:#CCC }   

/* workarounds */
html .ui-autocomplete { width:1px; } /* without this, the menu expands to 100% in IE6 */
.ui-menu {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu {
    margin-top: -3px;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    zoom: 1;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:.2em .4em;
    line-height:1.5;
    zoom:1;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-hover,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: -1px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for just giving us what we want... a definition of all the classes used for this control. Whilst I always resort to 'inspecting' items in the DOM for such things, the menu options closes whenever I load the web dev tools!!! - anyway thanks again :)

Comment: I second @Dal's comment.Works like a charm! good work. But, how did you get this CSS ? Your own custom styling ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the official jQuery ui autocomplete (i'm on 1.8.16) and would like to define the width manually, you can do so.

If you're using the minified version (if not then find manually by matching _resizeMenu), find...

```
_resizeMenu:function(){var a=this.menu.element;a.outerWidth(Math.max(a.width("").outerWidth(),this.element.outerWidth()))}
```

...and replace it with (add this.options.width|| before Math.max) ...

```
_resizeMenu:function(){var a=this.menu.element;a.outerWidth(this.options.width||Math.max(a.width("").outerWidth(),this.element.outerWidth()))}
```

... you can now include a width value into the .autocomplete({width:200}) function and jQuery will honour it. If not, it will default to calculating it.

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know you have two options for optimizing your code:

Instead of this:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('fontSize', '10px');
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('width','300px');
```

You can do this:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('fontSize', '10px').css('width','300px');
```

Or even better you should do this:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css({fontSize: '10px', width: '300px'});
```

Comment: or var mystyle = {fontSize: '10px', width: '300px'}; $('.ui-autocomplete-input').css(mystyle);

Comment: Sorry Nick, i guess i passed the wrong information. those codes change my input, not my result list. i want change the result. But thanks anyway for the shoot =)

Comment: Thanks for the sample too mark, i appreciate. But like i said to Nick, that is not the information that i'm looking for. thanks anyway =)

Comment: I'd like to take this time to respond to random downvotes. To be blunt it's stupid and helps no one, including your selfish self. By explaining why you downvoted you might help the author improve their answer, or save someone else the trouble of trying it as it didn't work.