# autocomplete does not show properly

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete

i am trying to autocomplete in text box and  this show but not properly show it.
because i am not find to perticular content class need to make css Please suggest me.
html:-

```
 <input type="text" id="surName" /><button id="add" class="hidden">Add</button>
  <label>Surname</label>
```

jquery:-

```
 abc = [...new Set(listOfabc.map(item => item.text))];
        $( "#surName" ).autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) { 
                var result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(abc, request.term);
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    $("#add").addClass("hidden")
                } else { 
                    $("#add").removeClass("hidden") 
                }
                response(result);

            }
        });
```

Comment: what do you mean with "this show but not properly show it"?

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly your problem is.

Comment: @Fabio this content is transference body and not any set css also

Comment: @mahit sir i am trying to find class  to this conent drowdown because make css

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409788/jquery-autocomplete-result-style this link may help you

Comment: @JituJoshi thank sir it working..

Comment: any suggestion for autocomplete attach on input in scrolling page